# How to change one route's Http field "withCredentials" to FALSE

Tags: angularjs, restangular

As part of a new registration form I am building right now, I need to pull a list of all available "Institutions" I have available at the time so that the user can tell me which one that they are registering for.

In the backend policies, I have set the controller action to be public:

```
InstitutionController: {
     // Some other policies I edited out
    'all': true
},
```

The controller is your standard "get all of objects" controller action.

```
all: function (req, res) {
    Institution
        .find()
        .exec(function (err, institutions) {
            if (err) { return res.json(err.status, err); }
            return res.json(institutions);
        });
},
```

So on the AngularJS frontend, I should be able to use `Institutions.all()` in my controller even before the user is logged in. This would be the case, however on the backend `passport` is trying to serialize and deserialize the (**non-existent**) user before it will perform this method.

Therefore, I get this error over at the API console:

```
error: Server Error:
error: Error: Failed to deserialize user out of session
at pass (/home/zacharyhustles/texasca-API/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:340:19)
at deserialized (/home/zacharyhustles/texasca-API/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:345:7)
at bound (/home/zacharyhustles/texasca-API/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
.......
```

How might I avoid passport serializing and deserializing the user when I try to perform this controller method `InstitutionController.all()`?

**UPDATE**

The problem is that this request is sending `withCredentials: true` because my default setting for HTTP fields with restangular is set to `true` in my application's `app.js` file:

**app.js**

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({ withCredentials: true });
```

If I set that to "false" the problem is solved. However, I do want most requests to the server to be sent "withCredentials" so I need a way to make an exception for this one request. As you can see, I am using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) in my application, so hopefully I can do this the Restangular way. Does anyone know how to do this?

Best, 
Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Restangular has added a way to set custom http fields per request. I have manually set `withCredentials : false` just for this one request. My modified backend call looks like this now:

```
return Restangular.all('institutions')
     .withHttpConfig({ withCredentials: false}).getList();
```

Before it was.

```
return Restangular.all('institutions').getList();
```